# Get the collection instead of the ID

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a [many-to-many](/questions/tagged/many-to-many) relationship between three tables (**Courses** , **Professors** , **Hours**) I created a 4th table called **course_hour_professors** to make the relation and I made it [one-to-many](/questions/tagged/one-to-many) relationship between the 4 tables because I know that if I get a pivot table with more than two FKs, I have to treat it as full model. So instead of Many-to-Many relationship. I have to divide it into multiple of One-to-Many relationships. all of this is working now  but **Professors** table is related to **User** table and I need to access the professor name which is located in the **User** table since it's related to it but I can only access the **User_id** from my **course_hour_professors** as shown below :

```json
  {
        "id": 3,
        "professor_id": 94,
        "course_id": 132,
        "hour_id": 1,
        "nbr_hour_course": 9,
        "course": {
            "id": 132,
            "created_at": "2018-07-25T16:02:19.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-07T07:38:01.000000Z",
            "name": "Algèbre - 1"
        },
        "professor": {
            "id": 94,
            "created_at": "2018-09-24T08:18:30.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-23T14:32:00.000000Z",
            "user_id": 810,
            "grade": "Maître assistant",
            "cin_delivered_at": "le 20/05/2015",
            "cnrps": "********",
            "cnss": "00000000",
            "phone": "********"
        },
        "hour": {
            "id": 1,
            "heure_suivie": 13,
            "type": "jour",
            "created_at": "2021-08-19T20:02:16.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-05T20:02:16.000000Z",
            "week_id": 1
        }
    }
```

**Professor Model** :

```php
class professor extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User",'user_id','id');
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\course');
    }

    public function hours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Hour');
    }

    public function courseHourProfessor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CourseHourProfessor', 'professor_id','id');
    }
}
```

**CourseHourProfessor Model** :

```php
class CourseHourProfessor extends Model
{
    public function professor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\professor', 'professor_id');
    }

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\course', 'course_id');
    }

    public function hour()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hour', 'hour_id');
    }
}
```

**Course Model**

```php
class Course extends Model
{
  public function professor()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\professor');
    }

  public function hours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Hour');
    }

    public function courseHourProfessor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CourseHourProfessor', 'course_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Hour Model** :

```php
class Hour extends Model
{
    //
    public function week()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Week::class);
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\course');
    }

    public function professors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\professor');
    }

    public function courseHourProfessor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CourseHourProfessor', 'hour_id','id');
    }
}
```

**CourseHourProfessor Controller** :

```php
public function getById($id)
     {
        return CourseHourProfessor::with(['course','professor','hour'])->where('id', $id)->get();
     }
```

I want to know if it's possible for the result to be  like this

```json
 {
        "id": 3,
        "professor_id": 94,
        "course_id": 132,
        "hour_id": 1,
        "nbr_hour_course": 9,
        "course": {
            "id": 132,
            "created_at": "2018-07-25T16:02:19.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-09-07T07:38:01.000000Z",
            "name": "Algèbre - 1"
        },
        "professor": {
            "id": 94,
            "created_at": "2018-09-24T08:18:30.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-23T14:32:00.000000Z",
            "user_id": 810,
            "grade": "Maître assistant",
            "cin_delivered_at": "le 20/05/2015",
            "cnrps": "********",
            "cnss": "00000000",
            "phone": "********"
            "user": {
                "id": 60,
                "email": "********@gmail.com",
                "name": "Aymen",
                "lastname": "********",
                "type": "professor",
                "birthday": "2018-01-01",
                "gender": "Male",
                "image_id": 34,
                "cin": "********",
                "fullname": "********Aymen"
        }
        },
        "hour": {
            "id": 1,
            "heure_suivie": 13,
            "type": "jour",
            "created_at": "2021-08-19T20:02:16.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-05T20:02:16.000000Z",
            "week_id": 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we not use 
return CourseHourProfessor::with(['user','course','professor','hour'])->where('id', $id)->get();

Comment: You provided some privacy sensitive data in your question...

Comment: @SandeepDhakal I don't think so because my **user** table and **course_hour_professors** table are not directly related to each other so there isn't any relation called **user** but they are both related to **professor** table

Comment: @WaafaOueslati you can do with('professor.user'), if its in relation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, what you want is a json :)

```
public function getById($id)
     {
        return CourseHourProfessor::with(['course','professor','hour'])->find($id)->toJson();
     }
```

Comment: yes but I want all the user details instead of only the user_id  but my **user** table and **course_hour_professors** table are not directly related to each other but they are both related to **professor** table